# Getting PHP Fatal error

Tags: php, fatal-error

I am getting the following error: PHP Fatal error:  Call to undefined function updateRecord()

I know that means that PHP is unable to locate the function I am calling.

I double checked the spelling of the function name and the include file at the top of the page, and both are correct.  I am not sure why PHP isn't recognizing the function in the included file.

Here is the code:

```
include_once('../lib/updatesEngine_lib.php');//include the file with the function
```

The function call:

```
updateRecord($jobid);
```

In updatesEngine_lib.php:

```
function updateRecord($jobid){//Code//}
```

I'm at a loss for why this isn't working.  Especially since there are other functions in the updateEngine_lib.php file that are structured similarly that are working.

HELP!

Comment: I accidentally deleted my comment - I'm the guy above - switch from include_once to require_once.  it will make your script stop with a fatal error if the file is not found.

Comment: he will get a warning as well and he says other functions from this file works all right

Comment: i switched the script to require_once, but that didn't do anything. I still get a PHP Fatal error saying that updateRecord is an undefined function.

Comment: I have to agree with your common sense, I know the include works, since other functions from that include are currently working. For some reason, only updateRecord results in a undefined function fatal error.

Comment: what if you call this function right from updatesEngine_lib.php - does it work?

Comment: You could also try copying the function into the local file and see if it works from there.  That might give you a hint of what is wrong.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Check your spelling for the third time or until you get it work.
There is no magic.
If it says "Call to undefined function" - so it is.

BTW, what if you call this function from updatesEngine_lib.php - does it work?

Comment: You were correct. It turned out that the dev before me was using a script to push changes from the SVN repo into the web root, but when he left, he turned permissions off for the script to push into the folder where this script went. So while I was making submissions correctly, it wasn't making it into the web root.